# Maths query in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am not very good in maths . So please don't mind my mistakes !
This is the question :

> Speedy kings are a racing group. Their leader John owns a Suzuki
>   Hayabusa which has a maximum speed of 300 kmph. The leader of the
>   rival group, Ranson owns a Ducati whose maximum speed is 280 kmph.
>   John makes n rounds of 10km track. How much time(in minutes) will
>   Ranson take to complete the same distance covered by John. Take the
>   value of n as input from the user. Sample Input: 4 Sample Output: 8

Now this is my solution :

```
class speedyKings{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int ducs=280;
        int hays=300;
        int total_dist=10000;
        int n=in.nextInt();
        double time=((10000*n)/280);
        System.out.print(time);
    }
}
```

But it is not giving the right output can anybody  help ?

Comment: output should be 8 but your logic is giving `142.0` @MorozovIvan

Comment: And why do you use 10000 as the distance? Length of track is 10km, speed is provided in km per hour. Just divide them and multiply by 60 to convert hours into minutes. Truncate it to fit the sample output. Truncate(4 * 10 / 280 * 60) = 8.

Comment: @MorozovIvan It should be (10 * n) /280. The track is in kilometers and the speed is in kilometers per hour. Then convert the answer to minutes.

Comment: Just use 2 * n * 300 / 280

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to take *small* steps to get to the right value. You can use appropriately named variables to remember what you're looking at and working with:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int laps = in.nextInt();
double speedInKph = 280; // km/h
double lapLength = 10000; // meter
double speedInMpS = speedInKph * 1000 / 3600; // m/s
double secondsPerLap = lapLength / speedInMpS; // m / (m/s) = s
double minutesPerLap = secondsPerLap / 60;
double minutes = minutesPerLap * laps;

System.out.println("Minutes: " + minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like that:

```
class SpeedyKings{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        double ducs = 280.0; 
        double hays = 300.0; 
        double track = 10.0;        
        double time = (track * n) / ducs * 60;
        System.out.print(time);
    }
}
```